# Style Vote stars and text

Tags: css

I have a Vote plugin in Joomla where there is stars and review text in one line. But the Stars are placed a little higher that the text. I have tried to move the Stars down with css / span, but i cant get it to move.

Ex : print . dk / folieprint

The code :

```
$final_avgreview_data  = '<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"><span style="display:none;" itemprop="name"> '.$title.' </span><span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">';
$final_avgreview_data .= '<span class="redshop_stars"><img src="'.REDSHOP_ADMIN_IMAGES_ABSPATH.'star_rating_ny/'.$avgratings.'.gif" /></span>';
$final_avgreview_data .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_RATING' ).' <span itemprop="ratingValue"> '.$avgratings.' </span> '.JText::_(' ' );
$final_avgreview_data .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_AVG_RATINGS_1' ).' <span itemprop="ratingCount"> '.$totalreviews.' </span> '.JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_AVG_RATINGS_2' );
$final_avgreview_data .= '<span style="display: none;" itemprop="bestRating">5</span>';
$final_avgreview_data .= '</span></div>';
```

Css :

```
span.redshop_stars {
margin: -10px 0 15px 0;
line-height: 11px;
padding: 0 0px !important;
}
```

How do i move the stars a little down?

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious -  have you tried changing `margin: -10px 0 15px 0;` to `margin: 0 0 15px 0;`

Comment: I tried it but it dont affect vertical (up/ down) position, only side ways.  Is there another way to do it than Margin?